# How do I remove the "stripe marks" from navigation bar and project window?

Tags: ide, webstorm

I use a [handlebars plugin to be used with requirejs](https://github.com/SlexAxton/require-handlebars-plugin) in my project. This makes Webstorm report an error if I require a template using the plugin-specific syntax:

`var template = require('hbs!./sometemplate.hbs');`

This is fine; I can easily control how the editor should present this error in my javascript file.

However, I cannot seem to figure out how to remove the "stripe marks", which appear in my navigation bar and project window:

[image]

How do I remove the red stripes from my windows, but not from the actual javascript file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. I can only suggest disabling error highlighting for the files where you use such require statements. This can be done using Hector icon in the lower right corner: open your file in editor, click the Hector icon and then move the slider to change the Highlighting level to None. See http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/changing-highlighting-level-for-the-current-file.html.

BTW, [WEB-1167](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-1167) is fixed, so using this plugin-specific syntax shouldn't be a problem in next release.

Comment: Thanks. Looking forward to next release then!